# CSV data config in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In my project, I need to pass 1 value for each thread and same value will be used for any number of times.
Is there any option in JMeter?

**For example:**

My question is simple.

In a thread group, i will assign 2 threads and 10 loops (10 loops for each thread).

My requirement is, I have to use first row data for first thread and same data should be used for 10 loops and second row data for second thread and same data should be used for 10 loops.

E.g.:
In csv file, I will declare as below:

```
43
42
45
46
```

During execution, thread 1 should always take 43 even for 10 loops, thread 2 should take 42 always.
45 and 46 should never be used if i declare just 2 threads in the test plan.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

```
Thread Group (2 threads, iteration : 1)
+-- Debug Sampler with Name : T-${__threadNum}-${__StringFromFile(/Volumes/HD2/csv.csv, line)}
+-- Loop Controller (Iterations : 10)
    +-- Debug Sampler to show you get what you need : T-${__threadNum}-DS-${line}
```

Test Plan:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.3" jmeter="2.8-SNAPSHOT.20120923">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">2</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1348513661000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1348513661000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <DebugSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugSampler" testname="T-${__threadNum}-${__StringFromFile(/Volumes/HD2/csv.csv, line)}" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
        </DebugSampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <LoopController guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">10</stringProp>
        </LoopController>
        <hashTree>
          <DebugSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugSampler" testname="T-${__threadNum}-DS-${line}" enabled="true">
            <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
          </DebugSampler>
          <hashTree/>
          <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
            <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
            <objProp>
              <name>saveConfig</name>
              <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
                <time>true</time>
                <latency>true</latency>
                <timestamp>true</timestamp>
                <success>true</success>
                <label>true</label>
                <code>true</code>
                <message>false</message>
                <threadName>true</threadName>
                <dataType>false</dataType>
                <encoding>false</encoding>
                <assertions>true</assertions>
                <subresults>false</subresults>
                <responseData>false</responseData>
                <samplerData>false</samplerData>
                <xml>false</xml>
                <fieldNames>false</fieldNames>
                <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
                <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
                <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
                <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
                <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
                <bytes>true</bytes>
                <hostname>true</hostname>
                <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
                <sampleCount>true</sampleCount>
              </value>
            </objProp>
            <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
          </ResultCollector>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

My question is simple,

In a thread group, i will be assigning 2 threads and 10 loops ( 10 loops for each thread)

My requirment is, I have to use first row data for first thread and same data should be used for 10 loops and second row data for second thread and same data should be used for 10 loops.

Eg: In csv file, I will declare as below, 43 42 45 46

While execution, Thread 1 should always take 43 even for 10 loops thread 2 should take 42 always. 45 and 46 should never be used if i declare just 2 threads in the test plan

Thanks Sadiq

Answer (score 0):

- Set thread group loop to 1.
- Enter a Loop Conroler with desired number of loops (in your case 10) **after** the CSV Data Set Config. Set sharing mode to: Current thread group.
- Add the HTTP request sampler as a child of Loop Controler and you got it:)

[image]